# Old canvas pixel data still there after resizing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a canvas and loading pixel data at certain pixel locations in the following way.

```js
let maskCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let patchWidth = 30;
let patchHeight = 30;
let scale = 3;  //scale up the canvas by 3 times
maskCanvas.setAttribute("class", "mask");
maskCanvas.style.position = "relative";
maskCanvas.width = patchWidth * scale;
maskCanvas.height = patchHeight * scale;
let maskCtx = maskCanvas.getContext("2d");
let maskImageData = maskCtx.createImageData(patchWidth, patchHeight);
row = [14, 19, 50, 71, 100, 240, 560, 640];    // Pixel locations where I want to set pixel color
row.forEach((pos, iter) => {
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 1] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 2] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 3] = 255;
});
maskCtx.putImageData(maskImageData, 0, 0);
maskCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

//resize the canvas according to scale
maskCtx.drawImage(maskCanvas, 0, 0, patchWidth, patchHeight, 0, 0, patchWidth * scale, patchHeight * scale);

document.querySelector(".myDiv").appendChild(maskCanvas);
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">

</div>
```

[image: Canvas image]

This is the output of the code snippet. It can be seen that the original pixel data before resizing is still there along with the resized canvas. How do i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)`= "copy"` compositing mode. Every new drawing will completely replace the destination (canvas pixels).

```js
let maskCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let patchWidth = 30;
let patchHeight = 30;
let scale = 3;  //scale up the canvas by 3 times
maskCanvas.setAttribute("class", "mask");
maskCanvas.style.position = "relative";
maskCanvas.width = patchWidth * scale;
maskCanvas.height = patchHeight * scale;
let maskCtx = maskCanvas.getContext("2d");
let maskImageData = maskCtx.createImageData(patchWidth, patchHeight);
row = [14, 19, 50, 71, 100, 240, 560, 640];    // Pixel locations where I want to set pixel color
row.forEach((pos, iter) => {
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 1] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 2] = 0;
  maskImageData.data[pos * 4 + 3] = 255;
});
maskCtx.putImageData(maskImageData, 0, 0);
maskCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

// every new drawing will replace completely current state
maskCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';

//resize the canvas according to scale
maskCtx.drawImage(maskCanvas, 0, 0, patchWidth, patchHeight, 0, 0, patchWidth * scale, patchHeight * scale);

// reset back to normal
maskCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

document.querySelector(".myDiv").appendChild(maskCanvas);
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of a function like this. This is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing twice on your canvas, what you should do is `drawImage` to new canvas.
see below I'm showing both canvases

```js
let maskCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let patchWidth = 30;
let patchHeight = 30;
let scale = 6;  //scale up the canvas 

maskCanvas.width = patchWidth * scale;
maskCanvas.height = patchHeight * scale;
let ctx = maskCanvas.getContext("2d");
let imageData = ctx.createImageData(patchWidth, patchHeight);
row = [14, 19, 50, 71, 100, 240, 560, 640];   
row.forEach((pos, iter) => {
  imageData.data[pos * 4] = 0;
  imageData.data[pos * 4 + 1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
  imageData.data[pos * 4 + 2] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
  imageData.data[pos * 4 + 3] = 255;
});
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

//resize the canvas according to scale
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = patchWidth * scale;
canvas.height = patchHeight * scale;

ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.drawImage(maskCanvas, 0, 0, patchWidth, patchHeight, 0, 0, patchWidth * scale, patchHeight * scale);

document.querySelector(".myDiv").appendChild(maskCanvas);
document.querySelector(".myDiv").appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, But your solution requires creation of one extra canvas element which may not be ideal for all the use cases in my problem

Comment: @hulkinBrain yes just like you, I was not aware of `globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';` but the extra canvas should not be a problem and you don't have to append both just the one you need to the final document... on this case `globalCompositeOperation` is the best way, but there are other cases where you need a second canvas, for instance, cases where you need to keep the original image for additional operations... just another tool in your arsenal

Comment: Yes indeed, I will for sure require your method too! Thanks a lot :D